# PCRE2: Check if a string matches a pattern without wasting time building match data?

Tags: c++, pcre

I'm trying to use PCRE2 in C++ (using the C API) to test whether a particular string matches a pattern. My use case is fairly performance sensitive, and I just need to do a boolean check about whether it matches or doesn't match.

I'm unable to find a way anywhere in the [API spec](http://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2api.html) to just check if a string matches a pattern without also allocating a match data block which PCRE2 will fill up. Is it actually impossible to just do a boolean test with PCRE2, or am I missing something?

If I'm building the regex like this:

```
int errnum; size_t erroffset;
pcre2_code *rx = pcre2_compile(
    (PCRE2_SPTR)some_regex_string, PCRE2_ZERO_TERMINATED, 0,
    &errnum, &erroffset, NULL);
/* error checking omitted */
```

Obviously that allocates, and that's fine, because it only happens once.
But then if I want a function to check whether a regex matches a string, the only way I can find to do it is something along the lines of:

```
bool does_regex_match(pcre2_code *rx, const char *str) {
    pcre2_match_data *md = pcre2_match_data_create_from_pattern(rx, NULL);
    int ret = pcre2_match(
        rx, (PCRE2_SPTR)str, PCRE2_ZERO_TERMINATED, 0, 0, md, NULL);

    pcre2_match_data_free(md);
    return ret >= 0; // ret will be negative on match failure
}
```

This isn't optimal, because it seems to do a whole lot of extra work. Even if I don't allocate and free the pcre2_match_data object every time, PCRE2 presumably does a lot of unnecessary work to populate the object, when I just need a simple boolean.

Comment: Show the regex you've got so far. In fact, make a [mre]. Have you considered using `std::regex` from the standard C++ library? Also, making it _without_ using regex is often faster.

Comment: Please _edit_ your question and post [in a code block here] the code you _do_ have. What you may need to do is dependent upon the API calls you're currently doing. Normally, you compile a regex _once_ and then pass a pointer to the context around. So, having an API call that has to allocate a fresh block on each match call seems strange to me. It certainly isn't necessary for the regex engine in [real] `perl`.

Comment: @CraigEstey alright, I updated the question to include code.

Comment: Is this compiled in C++ or C? Tagging with both languages is not helpful.

Comment: AFAICT, `pcre2_match_data_create_from_pattern` is _invariant_. It does _not_ depend upon the string you want to match. Move the call to it immediately after the `pcre2_compile` call. (i.e.) Call _it_ once, just as you call `pcre2_compile` once. Change _your_ function to take _three_ args: `bool does_regex_match(pcre2_code *rx, pcre2_match_data *md, const char *str)` Or, create a `struct` that contains the pointers to `rx` and `md` [and whatever else you need] and pass around a pointer to _that_ In other words, the _only_ thing that `does_regex_match` should do is to call `pcre2_match`

Comment: @tadman It doesn't matter. It's a C library, with headers which work both in C mode and in C++ mode. The API is identical. But if you must know, it's compiled in C++ mode.

Comment: It **does** matter. When you compile as C++ **different rules apply**. This is because it is a completely different programming language. It also means you can use `std::regex` which is why we're going to ask, again, why you aren't.

Comment: @tadman: I'm not using std::regex because I want perl-compatible regexes. My question is about the API of the PCRE library specifically, not "how do I match regexes in C++".

Comment: @CraigEstey: Yeah, that avoids the allocation, but as I wrote in the question; "Even if I don't allocate and free the pcre2_match_data object every time, PCRE2 presumably does a lot of unnecessary work to populate the object, when I just need a simple boolean"

Comment: The resolution might very well be that there's no way to use PCRE to just do a boolean test, and that filling in the match object doesn't take significant enough time to worry about. That would be fine if that's the case. I just want to know for sure.

Comment: Fair enough. We're just checking that this isn't some XY Problem where the goal is to solve a problem with regular expressions. In C you have very limited options, you must use a library like this. In C++ there are more options.

Comment: A [mre] which includes the actual regexes would help. Why do you think it does unnecessary work? Are you using non-capturing groups?

Comment: @TedLyngmo The regex is from user input. I don't control that.

Comment: If you're only interested in if it matches, you could make it all non-capture regardless where it comes from. It's only a little more work if you're not in control. What is it that makes you think that it's doing more work than you ask it to do? If you make it non-capturing, the object you get back should be pretty cheap. I've never used that API so I'm not sure if there are other functions available that does that automatically.

Comment: _PCRE2 **presumably** does a lot of unnecessary work to populate the object_ Can you prove this with benchmarks? Or, pull the source code for the library and examine `pcre2_match`. I did. 99.44% of the code is about matching/backtracking/etc [vs. storing into the struct], so, given that the match function handles [_can_ handle] complex regexes and multiline/whole file matching, I'd say it's as fast as it gets